# Using react-native-camera build error

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I just want use **react-native-camera** in my react-native project but has an error, I need help, I don't know what happened about this error. Looking forward to your answer, Thanks.

[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAsNL.png)

[android/app/build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcHuY.png)

Comment: You'll get a better response if you copy the error code and output into the stack question instead of posting a picture of the output

Answer (score 0):

There are two main possibilities:

- Add below line in build.gradle under compile project(':react-native-camera')

  compile (project(':react-native-camera')) {
      exclude group: "com.android.support"
  }
- As Camera module is used same TAG name as default native camera will use it:
  --> put code into react-native-camera --> src --> main --> java --> com.lwansbrough.RCTCamera --> RCTCameraModule

1) You need to add **RCTCameraModule** as a tag:

```
 public class RCTCameraModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule
    implements MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener, MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener, LifecycleEventListener {
    private static final String TAG = "RCTCameraModule";
...
}
```

2) Add this method

```
 @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "RCTCameraModule";
    }
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: i do that, but still the error, * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-camera'.
> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on o
bject of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: This issues is solved now, i just update buildToolsVersion to "26.0.2" and gradle to "gradle-4.4-all" then it's ok, thanks always.

Comment: Atleast we all come to know solution.